# How to connect my RadHtmlChart with SQL data

Tags: sql, visual-studio, radhtmlchart

I want to make a bar chart in Visual Studio. The data I want to display is in SQL. When I configure the data source it asks me to 'Specify a custom SQL statement or stored procedure'. I put this code into it

```
SELECT 'A' AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS A FROM TABLE1
WHERE VALIDATED = 'Y'
GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT 'B' AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS B FROM TABLE2
WHERE RESOLVED = 'N'
GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT 'C' AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS C FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY 1
```

and when I test the query it doesn't work. I have also tried saving a new table in SQL and connecting to the table but that also doesn't work.

Do you know why my code isn't working or how to make my chart work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding you will need a dataset that has the columns pulling the data you need, and you would reference those columns in your RadHTMLChart.

You can add a sqldatasource to your html, and add it to the RadHtmlChart.

One of the properties is **DataSourceID**, just set it equals to the name of your datasource, like this:  **DataSourceID**="*sqldatasource name*".

Then, on your LineSeries for example, you have the option of **DataFieldY**, set that to your Y series column name you are pulling from SQL.

On your X axis, there is a **DataLabelsField**, you can set that to the column you have in SQL for your X axis.

If this doesn't make sense, let me know.